# Kill process group

Tags: dart, dart-io

When I launch

```dart
io.Process.start(
    '~/google_cloud_datastore_dev_server/gcd-v1beta2-rev1-2.1.1/gcd.sh')
.then((process) {
  new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 10), () => process.kill());
});
```

With `Process.start` I get two new processes (the `gcd.sh` script and a Java application launched from `gcd.sh`). `process.kill()` only kills `gcs.sh` but the Java process keeps running.

Before `process.kill();`

```
pstree 24010
gcd.sh───java─┬─java───22*[{java}]
              └─20*[{java}]
```

After `process.kill();`

```
java─┬─java───21*[{java}]
     └─20*[{java}]
```

Is there a way to kill a process and all it's children (entire process group) from within Dart without reaching out to command line tools like `ps` or similar?

It's a bit cumbersome to process command output through stdin of launched processes and also difficult to make work cross-platform when using shell commands for this task.

Seems related: http://dartbug.com/3637

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no support for killing a process group in dart:io. I have opened http://dartbug.com/22470 to track this.